# Integrating BIOSTALL CI Google map Library

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

I am in a middle of a project and have integrated BIOSTALL CI library by Steve Marks and its working fine. However a design twist by client had made me collect multiple items under the same zip and show the list in marker. I have the array of items and I am trying to do something like this

```
$marker['infowindow_content']=$this->load->view('map_marker',$data,true);
```

But this is not working my map doesn't load after this statement. And I have no idea why.Though I mailed to Steve Marks directly and he happens to be very nice guy helped me out with another issue. This time however he seems busy. I was wondering if someone has ever done this before.

My current Map looks something [like this](http://104.238.102.6/~zerobytes/blue_lizard_audio/index.php/search)

My Markers Generation code is

```
$zip_codes=$this->search_model->get_zip_codes();

    for($i=0;$i<count($zip_codes);$i++)
    {
        $data['marker_items']=$this->search_model->get_items_by_zip_code($zip_codes[$i]['zip']);
        $marker = array();
        $marker['position'] = $data['marker_items'][0]['latitude'].','.$data['marker_items'][0]['longitude'];
        $marker['infowindow_content']=$this->load->view('map_marker',$data,true);
        $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='.count($data['marker_items']).'|9999FF|000000';
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    }
    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

I wonder if someone can help

Comment: My Problem is solved however, I learned that to display a complete HTML / PHP file in infowindow_content it needs to be written and styled inline. 

Thanks to all I am closing this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->library('googlemaps');
    $config['center'] = 'auto';
    $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
    $config['kmlLayerURL'] = 'localhost/khair/google_map/detail';
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
    $marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = '28.6457559,  76.8105583';
    $marker['infowindow_content'] = 'Hi';
    $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

    $marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = '28.6998822, 77.2549408';
    $marker['draggable'] = TRUE;
    $marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

    $marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = '28.5486782, 77.4549395';
    $marker['onclick'] = 'alert("You just clicked me!!")';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

    /*You can use foreach() to repeat $marker array and values with conditions. */

    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
    $this->load->view('google_map',$data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload googlemaps library

```
$this->load->library('googlemaps');
// set config
$config['zoom'] = 'auto';
$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
```

and to load into view use below code no need to assign it into array

```
 $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
 $this->load->view('map_marker',$data);// not need to pass it in array
```

**View File:**

```
<html>
<head><?php echo $map['js']; ?></head>
<body><?php echo $map['html']; ?></body>
</html>
```

Also read [CI google api](http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/)

Comment: Thanks Saty for a quick response but as I mentioned I need list of items to be displayed in infowindow_content . If I don't include the statement
      $marker['infowindow_content']=$this->load->view('map_marker',$data,true);

The map loads fine but when I use this statement and dump the map in the view it returns nothing

Comment: All I am asking, Can I use another php file to display dynamic contents in marker['infowindow_content']

Comment: Thanks to whoever viewed this conversation. My testing link is [here](http://104.238.102.6/~zerobytes/blue_lizard_audio/index.php/search) . I have no idea how long it will stay valid because we are still in development phase but I will publish the live link as soon as it is hosted live.